# Try..With Block is hanging after the First Error F#

Tags: f#

I am fairly new to F# and my code is "hanging" after the first instance of an error.  It just does nothing really.

This is at the very end of a function the call is a SOAP call to an API endpoint.

```
        try 
            let a = client.catalogProductCreateAsync(sessionId, "simple","4",priceListItem.sku, productData, "").Result
            printfn "%A" a
        with ex ->
            printfn "%A" ex
        "" // blank string returned - not relevant to the above - it's just the end of the funciton
```

Comment: Does the code print the exception before hanging?  What does the caller of the function look like?  The question doesn't really have enough information to diagnose the problem.  What is the code supposed to do?  What does it do if the `client.catalogProductCreateAsync` call doesn't throw?